# Is nicename the same as nickname in WP?

Tags: users, admin

In Admin Dashboard > Users > Your Profile, I see only nickname not nicename.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not the same. The nickname is essentially just a meta field for the user to set a name for themselves in a single field that isn't their login or first/last name. `user_nicename` on the other hand is the field that's used for the users author archive URL, when viewing their posts (if they have any). It's not editable from the profile.